# What does the $PLUGINSDIR keyword pointing to in NSIS Script

Tags: nsis

I need to read a content from .ini file while installing my package. so before installing i want to place my ini file in a corressponding directory to read while indatlling my package. so, What does the $PLUGINSDIR keyword pointing to in NSIS Script

```
ReadINIStr '${TEMP1}' "$PLUGINSDIR\builder.ini" "Field 2" "State"
       StrCpy '$FILE_NAME' '${TEMP1}'
```

need to know the exact folder directory pointing to the $PLUGINSDIR thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's a temporary folder created by an installer (see [InitPluginsDir](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/InitPluginsDir.md)) and it changes everytime you start the installer. It's usually a directory sitting in your temporary folder named *nsXXX.tmp* with XXX being a random string.

If you want to see it *in action*, try calling **ExecShell open $PLUGINSDIR** after initializing the directory!

Comment: Section GetIP 0
   HideWindow
 
   ReadINIStr '${TEMP1}' "$PLUGINSDIR\Test.ini" "FIELDS" "file"
   StrCpy '$FILE_NAME' '${TEMP1}'
SectionEnd   i used like this but got an error as Usage: ReadINIStr $(user_var: output) ini_file section entry_name
So still in confusion... help me where to place my .ini file then...

Comment: what did you define for ${TEMP1} ?